# Why don’t make check the timestamp when the dependency file is not generated?

Tags: makefile, gnu

I create an ugly Makefile, it worked beyond my expectations. When main.o is not built successfully, the executable is built every time I make. In my opinion, after the main.o target command is executed, make will compare the timestamp of the main.o file with the main file. There is no main.o file at this time, so the main file should be the latest. Why is the command of the main target executed. In my case main is always present after the first build and it is rebuilt each time make is executed, Although the content is the same

When I add a main.o file that is older than main by shell, I change the main.c file and use the make command to update only main1.o, but not main, indicating that make compares main and main.o timestamp.

Is there a problem with my understanding? Is it my misunderstanding of the execution process of make.

```
main: main.o
    gcc -o main main1.o
    echo generate

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main1.o
```

Comment: Because you told GCC to write `main1`, Make will re-build until you create `main`.  Also, `main.o` never gets created.  Pro-tip: use `-o $@` to avoid such inconsistencies.

Comment: I suggest to read https://make.mad-scientist.net/ and specifically https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/

Comment: In my case,  the main is existed, and main.o never gets created, so why target main‘s command is executed.

Comment: @Bodo I know that if I engage in unrecommended behavior, there will be unexpected results. I just want to know exactly how the makefile works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this:

```
main: main.o
        <create some-other-file>

main.o: main.c
        <create yet-another-file>
```

Make wants to build `main`.  It sees that before it can build `main`, it needs to build `main.o`.  It looks at your directory and sees there is no file `main.o`, so it runs your recipe.  Your recipe builds `yet-another-file`, but make doesn't check for that: make believes that whatever your recipe did, it will satisfy the target you told make that it would satisfy.  In other words, it trusts that the makefile author wrote a recipe that did what they intended to do, whatever that was.

Then make runs the recipe for `main`, which builds `some-other-file`.  If that recipe needed `main.o`, then it would fail (presumably).  It didn't fail, so make says all good.

Then you run `make` again, and it sees that `main.o` doesn't exist, so it builds it, then it builds `main`, etc. as many times as you run `make`.

If your question is, shouldn't make fail when it sees that the recipe to build the target like `main.o` *didn't* actually build the target, the answer is "that's not now make works".  There are actually *tons* of situations where you don't want the recipe to build the target.  Just as one example, consider a rule like:

```
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

... would fail because it doesn't create a target `clean`.

Comment: So why if I create a main.o myself, make it older than main, and make after every change to the.c file, make will compare the timestamps of main.o and main and decide not to generate main, but only do the update to the target main.o (actually main1.o）

Comment: Can it be said that if the dependency file exists, the timestamp will be compared, if the dependency file does not exist after the command is executed, it will be directly considered to be the latest

Comment: When make finishes building a target it checks to see if that target was updated.  A file is not updated if it existed before the recipe and it existed after the recipe, and the timestamp is the same.  In any other situation, it's considered updated.  So, if your recipe runs and for some reason decided to not change the target, then anything depending on the target won't consider that prerequisite to be updated.  None of this applies if your recipe builds a DIFFERENT target.  Make has no idea what other files might be updated and can't know anything about them.

Answer (score 0):

> *There is no main.o file at this time, so the main file should be the latest*

That is false. when a prerequisite file is missing, Make treats that situation as requiring the target to be rebuilt. It's the same as if the prerequisite existed, and were newer than the target.

Say we have `prog: foo.o bar.o` rule, and either `foo.o` or `bar.o` are missing (or both). Make then assumes `prog` must be updated, and in order for that to happen, `foo.o` and `bar.o` must be brought into existence. Make will look for a way to create `foo.o` and `bar.o`. (If it is not able to, then it will bail with an error message, like "No rule to build `foo.o`, needed by `prog`"). Having done that, `foo.o` and `bar.o` now exist **and are newer than `prog`**. So `prog` must be updated.

This is because Make is purely timestamp-based. A build system based on comparing file contents (e.g. via hashes) could skip building `prog` if `foo.o` and `bar.o` are missing, but have the same hash as when they were previously built.

Secondly, you have to understand that Make believes your rules. If you have a rule like `a: b`, followed by a recipe of commands, you are **declaring** to Make that `a` depends on `b` and that your rule updates `a`.  If the rule does not update `a`, then **you're lying to Make**, **and Make believes you**.

Unless you created `main.o` manually, it doesn't exist. Your Makefile builds no such file. Make sees that `main.o` is a prerequisite of `main`, that it is missing and that you have a rule to create `main.o`. So it runs your recipe to build `main.o`. **And then it believes that your successfully executed recipe must have updated `main.o`**.  It assumes there is now a `main.o` which is newer than `main`, and so it runs the rule to update `main`. That rule updates `main` using `main1.o`, not `main.o`.

Since `main.o` is always missing, Make will always try to rebuild it, run your rule which doesn't rebuild it, and then always assume that `main.o` has now been built and `main` must be built. Thus `main.o` and `main` get built each time.

The solution is to write rules that actually update their declared target.